# Is there a recommendable Prolog IDE for the Mac?

Tags: macos, ide, prolog

I'd love to do some stuff in Prolog. Just need a good IDE for the Mac to make it not a pain in the butt. Which IDE do you recommend?

Comment: VSCode with the VSC-Prolog extension also works well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Along the lines of "not really an IDE" answers, [Textmate](http://macromates.com/) seems to be a favorite of OS X developers.

There seems to be some Prolog community support for it as well.

- https://github.com/textmate/prolog.tmbundle
- http://calltopower.wordpress.com/2009/01/23/prolog-textmate-plugin/

Comment: You may also use TextMate's Logtalk bundle for Prolog programming.

Answer (score 4):

There is also a free Prolog IDE based on Eclipse, PDT, available from:

https://sewiki.iai.uni-bonn.de/research/pdt/start

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly about IDes but the current Logtalk distribution includes support for several text editors and syntax highlighters that can also be used for Prolog programming:

http://trac.logtalk.org/browser/trunk/wenv

The Prolog FAQ also contains useful information about editing and publishing Prolog code (sections 15 and 16):

http://www.logic.at/prolog/faq/

Answer (score 1):

There are several plugin's available for Eclipse which work rather well with prolog. Theres a SICStus plug in which we use in Uni, although I dont believe its free, theres also a few other options in the Eclipse Marketplace (Under the Help menu)

Answer (score 0):

Try [CiaoDE](http://clip.dia.fi.upm.es/) plus GNU Emacs. CiaoDE is a state of the art prolog system with lots of libraries that runs in OS X, Linux and Windows.

Comment: Does not work with Mac OS X...

Comment: Well, I use it in both Linux and Mac OS X. If you need some help installing or using it, please ask me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [XGP](http://xgp.sourceforge.net/) for this.